# How to add onCompleteListener when signing in with Firebase Auth pre-built UI?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using [prebuilt Firebase UI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui) to authenticate user such as below:

```
val providers = arrayListOf(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build())

startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN)
```

How do I attach a `OnCompleteListener` during sign-in? More specifically, I want to call `getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser()` to check if the user is first time log in. I know I can add `onCompleteListener` if I sign in using [email and password-based method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth), but I want to handle multiple sign-in providers using the prebuilt UI method above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onActivityResult` you receive the result for the sign in with some data passed as `Parcelable` which u are already overriding for validation!

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

        // this class has all the needed data !
        val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Successfully signed in            
            val isNewUser = response?.isNewUser!! // flag to check if the user is first time login 
        } 
    }
}
```

@See class `IdpResponse` of package `com.firebase.ui.auth`:-

**Dug a bit deep for you** ;) Happy coding!

Comment: Do you mean I can check from `IdpResponse` whether a user is first time log in?

Comment: yeah , it has a boolean field called `isNewUser`, i have added the code @Neoh